# Account class Error

Tags: java, account

I am getting an error on this program for some reason and I have no idea what it means. I tried googling around, but nothing related to my issue is coming up. Does this have to do with an IOException by any chance? Also, where does the input get stored? In the class file? For example: if I was to input money into the account, would the inputed value be saved in a different file, or does the fact that I made an array of 30 account for a double amount of all 30 objects created?

Main class:

```
        import java.util.Scanner;
import java.text.NumberFormat;
public class Account2
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    Account[] acct = new Account[30];
    System.out.println("Enter your account number (1-30): ");
    int key = scan.nextInt() - 1;
    int reset = 0;
    while (reset == 0)
    {
      System.out.println("Enter W for withdrawl; D for deposit; X to escape");
      char choice = scan.next().charAt(0);

      if  (choice == 'W' || choice == 'w' || choice == 'D' || choice == 'd' || choice == 'x' || choice == 'X')
      {
        if (choice == 'W' || choice == 'w')
        {
          System.out.println("Enter amount to withdraw: ");
          Double withdraw1 = scan.nextDouble();
          if (withdraw1 <= acct[key].getBalance())
          {
            acct[key].withdraw(withdraw1);
            System.out.println("User # " + key++ + " funds after withdraw: " + acct[key].getBalance() + "$");
            System.out.println("User # " + key++ + " funds after interest: " + acct[key].addInterest() + "$");
            reset++;
          }
          else
            System.out.println("Insufficient funds.");
        }

        if (choice == 'D' || choice == 'd')
        {
          System.out.println("Enter amount to deposit: ");
          Double deposit1 = scan.nextDouble();
          if (deposit1 > 0)
          {
            acct[key].deposit(deposit1);
            System.out.println("User # " + key++ + " funds after deposit: " + acct[key].getBalance() + "$");
            System.out.println("User # " + key++ + " funds after interest: " + acct[key].addInterest() + "$");
            reset++;
          }
          else
            System.out.println("Use the withdrawl feature to withdrawl money.");

        }
        if (choice == 'x' || choice == 'X')
          System.out.println("Thank You for using this bank.");
          reset++;
      }
      else
        {
          System.out.println("Invalid entry, please try again");
          reset = 0;
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Second Class:

```
import java.text.NumberFormat; //links to Part2

public class Account
{
  private final double RATE = 0.03; //Interest is 3%

  private long acctNumber;
  private double balance;
  private String name;

  //Defines owner, account number, and initial balance.
  public Account(String owner, long account, double initial)
  {
    name = owner;
    acctNumber = account;
    balance = initial;
  }

  //deposits a specified amount and returns new balance
  public double deposit(double amount)
  {
    balance = balance + amount;
    return balance;
  }

  //withdraws the specified amount from the account and applies the fee
  //                                                  + returns balance
  public double withdraw(double amount)
  {
    int fee = 1;
    balance = balance - amount - fee;
    return balance;
  }

  //Adds interest to the account
  public double addInterest()
  {
    balance += (balance * RATE);
    return balance;
  }
  public double getBalance()
  {
    return balance;
  }

  //returns a one line description of the account as a string
  public String toString()
  {

    NumberFormat fmt = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
    return acctNumber + "/t" + name + "/t" + fmt.format(balance);
  }
}
```

Error message:

```
Enter your account number (1-30):
5
Enter W for withdrawl; D for deposit; X to escape
d
Enter amount to deposit:
50
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at Account2.main(Account2.java:40)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to acces an index of `acct` but the array is empty `Account[] acct = new Account[30];`

You should first fill the array, try to make the user create an account first.

Comment: Ohh, good Idea. I'll do this, and also, what do you mean it is empty? Isnt the starting value of an object of type double always 0?

Comment: @Submersed24 Yes, but here you have an array of `Account` objects, not `double`'s. Do not forget to accept the answer :)

Comment: Thanks for the help, and by filling the array, do you mean by making a for loop that sets acc[0]-acc[29] up with the value 0?

Comment: @Submersed24 You can fill the array you want to. But if an array of objects is not filled, you'll get the exception.

Comment: Ohh, so you fill the array with any type the method calls for? Is an array of objects like a class?

Comment: I did this as a way to set every acct[] array to 0:                                                 `for (int count2 = 0; count2 < 30; count2++)
    {
      acct[count2] = 0;`

Comment: I am just a little confused on how you would fill an array of objects, when an array is just a bunch of methods. Could you further explain what you need to fill in the array of objects? Thanks.